# Android Lollipop Theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I want a white EditText.
Which theme shall I use?

I can customize the rest of the looks.

I searched for any xml file also, to find which one could I use as the drawable background, but did not find one.
Can anyone suggest any xml or theme?

The EditText now is black.
I want it to be white colored and same design.
I.e.: just a line, not  the braces at the end.

I have looked into the drawable folder of the API 22 SDK, but it did not help...
I got only One solution, but it gives the older EditTexts in white colour.

Like this one

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In android manifest file apply the  theme .

```
<activity
            android:name="your activity name"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >
```

in the values-v14 folder change the style to below

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: change your activity in manifest file accordingly to this custom style. Actually it is worked for me. no need to apply any backgrounds / drawable for the edittext